# Is this race now completely wiped out?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Just a few **Children of the Forest** have been seen throughout *Game of Thrones*.

However, in the fifth episode of season six,

> the White Walkers raid the Tree, and kill the Three-Eyed Raven, the Children of the Forest and Summer, Bran's Wolf.

Were these the last remaining Children of the Forest?

Comment: I think the answer is we don't know yet.  We didn't know that any CotF existed until Bran met them hanging out with the Three Eyed Raven.

Comment: What I ment was if there are some mentions in a books or if G.R.R.M said something ;)

Comment: @kuhl we've known in the books and in the special features since season 1

Comment: @cde correct me if I'm wrong, we've known that the CotF DID exist, not that they still do.  We found that out in the books and the show when Bran met the Three Eyed Raven. So to my knowledge we have no idea if there are more or if this group was the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitively not known.

In the books, there is a Child of the Forest who sometimes appears on a hill to the members of the Brotherhood Without Banners.

Comment: If I recall correctly there is no proof that she is really a Child of the Forest.

Comment: Fair point @Chanandler Bong, but it is very strongly implied.